# Difference between compiling java app with maven and intellij idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I develop a java web app in intellij which is then deployed to tomcat (tomcat integrated with intellij). It is a maven project.
So, usually I do this:
I run package goal in maven. Then I run tomcat in intellij.
Or I may not package it with maven and run tomcat in intellij right away.
So what is the difference then?

If I package it with maven and then run tomcat in intellij does the source code get compiled and packaged again and then deployed? Or just war produced by maven goal is deployed  to tomcat?
Well if I don't package it and just run tomcat in intellij then it obviously gets compiled by intellij goal. 
I am a bit confused here.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to run `mvn package` before running your webapp within Intellij. 
What you can do is configure your Tomcat server to run your war **exploded**.

In the run/debug configuration, you can specify before launch operation.
By default,

- a make is done
- build artifact in exploded mode is done

If you prefer to work with a-non exploded war, last step would be build artifact instead of build exploded artifact.

[image]

Comment: Are you suggesting that no matter if I compiled my code with maven, every time I run tomcat source code gets compiled again? And I noticed one thing that if I e.g. added new spring bean to my code it wouldn't be picked up by spring unless I compile it with maven.